# I have a small line appearing beneath icons I am using as links

Tags: html, css

I am adding twitter and facebook icons to my website and using them as links to my accounts, however for some reason there are small lines appearing beneath the icons as per the screenshot.

I have used text decoration none and outline none to try and get rid of them.

If I remove the href from the code the lines disappear.

Heres my html

```
<div class="box mm">
       <ul class="nav">
       <li><a href="http://twitter.com/skramshots"> <img class="twitter"     src="images/twitterx.png" alt="twitter link" width="30" /> </a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/webpage.skramshots?fref=ts"> <img class="facebook" src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook link" width="30" /> </a></li>
       <li><img class="btn lightbox-61896367686376 email" src="images/email2.png" width="20" alt="email link" /></li></ul>

       <h1>SkramShots<br>Photography</h1><br><h2>Move your mouse pointer over the images</h2></div>
```

and heres my css

```
.nav {
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}

.nav li {

display: inline;
margin-left: 20%;


}

.nav li img {
margin-bottom: 45px;
margin-top: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;

}
```

any help very much appreciated.
[screenshot of lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW6i9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying text-decoration to the wrong tag. It needs to applied to the `<a></a>` tag.

```
 .nav li a{
      text-decoration:none;
    }
```

Comment: You can't just copy the question's code and paste to be the FGITW

Comment: I did not pasted the question. I pasted the solution which I tried on the fiddle.

Comment: That worked. Thanks very much for your help. Very much appreciated. I am relatively new to coding so I keep running into snags :)